# Google Place Autocomplete showing 'street_number' in the results (predictions) in dropdown, but not in the .getPlace() Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using the JavaScript code and HTML available in the link:
[Google Places address form example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

The question I have is regarding this specific search string: 77 Soi Tiwanon 2 Nonthaburi Thailand

If I type the string mentioned above, I see the result(predictions) as part of the dropdown, but when I select the value from the result, somehow the Street_Number value is not returned by following line of code:

```
 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

Q: Why does the result (predictions) dropdown shows the street number value '77', But when I click on the result, it does NOT populate the streetnumber in the textbox.

Is there any work around for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Google Places API.

Here's a bug filed against the API: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6715

Using the [Places Autocomplete test tool](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), it's pretty clear that some addresses **do** return the street_number value while others do not.

**Working**: "123 Main Street, Los Altos, CA"

**Broken**: "20750 Midstar Dr Bowling Green, OH"

Comment: That bug link did help, appreciate your response. Hopefully we will have resolution from Google Places team sooner.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the same issue on a site I built recently, and the more votes we get on that bug, the more likely they are to fix it soon!